# How do i view logs for my Kubernetes Ingress Controller?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I have recently started to learn about Kubernetes and i'm trying understand why my ingress controller is giving a 502 error.

i'm working with google cloud platform. i can see my service of type: LoadBalancer is working if i connect using its static IP address, but it seems i may not have configured my ingress controller correctly because it gives a 502 error.

but it doesn't display any error when i deploy and i cant find any logs for the Ingress so i cant see why a 502 is being displayed.

Comment: Are you using Google Container Engine (GKE) or Google Compute Engine (GCE)?

Comment: I'm using GKE, but if logs are available for GCE, I'd still like to know in case it is ever useful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On GKE, Ingress logs are in the web console under Stackdriver Logging, under "Cloud HTTP Load Balancer":

[image]

Comment: I don't see "Cloud HTTP Load Balancer" in the dropdown list anymore. I'm having a weird random 502 error and need to check load balancer log, please help.

Comment: Any idea to do it with the CLI ?

Answer (score 9):

I got logs in CLI using namespace and label.

```
kubectl logs -n ingress-nginx -l app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
```

Display ingress labels

```
kubectl get ingress --show-labels
```

I found namespace ("ingress-nginx") in the web interface of my cloud platform.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467929/accessing-nginx-ingress-controller-error-log

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to view them the same as any other pod (`kubectl logs -n namespace-name pod-name`). The name and namespace will change depending on which ingress controller you're using.

Be aware that ingress controllers are often setup in a different namespace, so you may need to look for the pod in those. For example, the default configuration of the nginx ingress uses the namespace 'nginx-ingress'.

Comment: This is returns an error because it thinks it's looking for a pod rather than an ingress

Comment: The ingress controller is a pod in almost all cases.

Comment: The GKE Ingress controller runs on a managed master node by GCP, not as a regular pod, so you are not able to view its logs or runa ny `kubectl` operations on it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was for AWS EKS but that shouldn't matter much. My ingress had no label so @chalex2k's answer didn't work for me. However, I was able to bring up all the events on it at least with: `kubectl get events --all-namespaces` or `kubectl get events -n namespace-name`.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an updated version of Abe Voelker's answer, since the UI has changed in 5 years, along with the flows.

Others have given good answers if you're using nginx-ingress. However, if you're using an "External HTTP(S) LB," you can find them in "Logs Explorer" under the "Application Load Balancer" Resource Type. You can further filter by URL Map or Forwarding Rule if you have multiple LBs.

[image: Google Cloud Console - Logging - Logs Explorer - where to find LB logs]